# Intuitive explanation why "shadow operator" $\frac D{e^D-1}$ connects logarithms with trigonometric functions?

Tags: operator-theory, intuition, big-picture, fourier-transform, integral-transforms

Consider the operator $\frac D{e^D-1}$ which we will call "shadow":

$$\frac {D}{e^D-1}f(x)=\frac1{2 \pi }\int_{-\infty }^{+\infty } e^{-iwx}\frac{-iw}{e^{-i w}-1}\int_{-\infty }^{+\infty } e^{i t w} f(t) \, dt \, dw$$

The integrals here should be understood as Fourier transforms.

Now, intuitively, why the following?

$$\left.\frac {D_x}{e^{D_x}-1} \left[\frac1\pi\ln \left(\frac{x+1/2 +\frac{z}{\pi }}{x+1/2 -\frac{z}{\pi }}\right)\right]\right|_{x=0}=\tan z$$

There are other examples where shadow converts trigonometric functions into inverse trigonometric, logarithms to exponents, etc:

$$\left.\frac {D_x}{e^{D_x}-1} \left[\frac1{\pi }\ln \left(\frac{x+1-\frac{z}{\pi }}{x+\frac{z}{\pi }}\right)\right]\right|_{x=0}=\cot z$$

Comment: Cant we expand $\frac{D}{e^D-1}$ as $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} {B^{-}_{k}} \frac{D^k}{k!}$?

Comment: @AlapanDas. Yes. Currently there are some mistakes in the formulas, I am fixing this.

Comment: @AlapanDas fixed typos

Comment: I think the second example may not be the most enlightening, given the relation $\cot z = \tan \left(\frac{\pi}{2} - z\right)$. Do you happen to have another?

Comment: @AlapanDas yes, with hyperbolic arctangent, but it also can be derived from this example, I think. Also, with logarithm and exponent, but looks not nice.

Comment: How can we define the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{it\omega}f(t) dt$ for $f(t)=\frac{1}{\pi}\ln|\frac{x+0.5+z/\pi}{x+0.5-z/\pi}|$ blows up at $x=z/\pi -0.5$ .

Comment: @AlapanDas this is a formal expression, one can hope there is a regularization. I use another (less rigorous) way to calculate this operator (I put in Mathematica Sum[D[f[x],x],x] which usually produces the needed result)

Answer (score 30):

This is basically a lightly transformed version of Euler's cotangent partial fraction expansion
$$ \pi \cot(\pi z) = \frac{1}{z} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{z-n} + \frac{1}{z+n}$$
(the log derivative of his famous sine product formula $\frac{\sin \pi z}{\pi z} = \prod_{n=1}^\infty \big(1-\frac{z^2}{n^2}\big)$).  By telescoping series one can rewrite this as
$$ \pi \cot(\pi z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{z-n-1} + \frac{1}{z+n}.$$
By Taylor's theorem, $e^{nD_x}$ is the operation of translation by $n$, so formally by geometric series we have
$$ \left.\frac{1}{1-e^{D_x}} f\, \right|_{x=0} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left.e^{nD_x} f\right|_{x=0} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty f(n)$$
(which incidentally helps explain the Euler-Maclaurin formula) and so
$$ \pi \cot(\pi z) = \left.\frac{1}{1-e^{D_x}} \left(\frac{1}{z-x-1} + \frac{1}{z+x}\right) \right|_{x=0}$$
or equivalently
$$ \pi \cot(\pi z) = - \left.\frac{D_x}{1-e^{D_x}} \ln \frac{x+z}{x+1-z} \right|_{x=0}.$$
This gives your identities after some simple rearrangements (and replacing $z$ with either $z/\pi$ or $z/\pi + 1/2$).

The primary reason for Euler's partial fraction identity is that the poles and residues of the cotangent function are easily identified and computed.  The reason they can be collapsed into an expression involving the summation operator $\frac{1}{1-e^{D_x}}$ is that these poles and residues enjoy a translation invariance, which ultimately comes from the periodicity of the cotangent function.  I would imagine there are similar identities for the Weierstrass $\wp$ function, which is doubly periodic with very specific pole behavior.

Comment: Thanks. We here have a case where essentially inverse trigonometric functions are linked to trigonometric functions. This is a very interesting topic for me, especially given this "shadow operator" (or Todd operator) plays a crucial role here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/115743/an-algebra-of-integrals/342651#342651 So I was asking for a deeper intuition, maybe of algebraic nature.

Answer (score 11):

The op $$T_x = \frac{D_x}{e^{D_x}-1} = e^{b.D_x},$$

where $(b.)^n = b_n$ are the Bernoulli numbers, is (mod signs) often referred to as the [Todd operator](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/266046/transformation-converting-power-series-to-bernoulli-polynomial-series/266058#266058) (maybe originally given that name by Hirzebruch, who used it to construct his Todd characteristic class).

It has a discretizing (or derivational) property that can be expressed in the following  useful ways

$$f(x) = T_x T_x^{-1} f(x) = \frac{D}{e^D-1} \frac{e^D-1}{D}  f(x) =  T_x \int_{x}^{x+1} f(t) dt$$

$$ = e^{b.D} \;\int_{x}^{x+1} f(t) dt = \int_{b.+x}^{b.+x+1} f(t) dt =\int_{B.(x)}^{B.(x)+1} f(t) dt$$

$$ = F(B.(x)+1) - F(B.(x)) = F(B.(x+1)) - F(B.(x)) = D_x \; F(x),$$

where

$$B_n(x) = (b.+x)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \; b_k \; x^{n-k}$$

are the celebrated Appell Bernoulli polynomials, with the e.g.f. $e^{B.(x)t}= e^{(b.+x)t} = \frac{t}{e^t-1}e^{xt}$, and $F(x)$ is the indefinite integral/primitive  of $f(x)$. The last equality illustrates the derivational property of the Bernoulli polynomials and completely defines them.

This leads to

$$\sum_{k=0}^n f(x+k) = T \; \int_{x}^{x+n+1} f(t) dt $$

$$ = e^{b.D} \; \int_{x}^{x+n+1} f(t) dt =  \int_{B.(x)}^{B.(x+n+1)} f(t) dt$$

$$ = F(B.(x+n+1)) - F(B.(x)),$$

and, in particular, the string of relations

$$\sum_{k=0}^n (x+k)^s =T_x \;  \int_{x}^{x+n+1} t^{s} dt  $$

$$= e^{b.D}  \int_{x}^{x+n+1} t^{s} dt =  \int_{B.(x)}^{B.(x+n+1)} t^s dt$$

$$ =  T_x \; \frac{(x+n+1+)^{s+1} -x^{s+1}}{s+1} =  e^{b.D} \frac{(x+n+1+)^{s+1} -x^{s+1}}{s+1}$$

$$ = \frac{(B.(x+1+n))^{s+1} -(B.(x))^{s+1}}{s+1} = \frac{B_{s+1}(x+1+n) - B_{s+1}(x)}{s+1}$$

$$ = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{B_{s+1}(x+1+k) - B_{s+1}(x+k)}{s+1}$$

$$ = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(B.(x+1+k))^{s+1} - (B.(x+k))^{s+1}}{s+1}$$

$$ =  \sum_{k=0}^n D_x \; \frac{(x+k)^{s+1}}{s+1}.$$

If you appropriately take the limit $s \to -1$, you arrive at a relation to the natural logarithm from whence, along with the series expansions of the trig functions in Terry Tao's answer, you can tease out your particular formulas.

For a more sophisticated illustrative application of the discretizing formula, see Eqn. 1, "the Khovanskii-Pukhlikov formula, the combinatorial
counterpart to the Hirzebruch-Riemann-Roch formula (HRR) for a smooth
toric variety X with a very ample divisor D ... " on page 2 of the "$T_y$-[operator on integrals over lattice polytopes](http://www.math.sci.hokudai.ac.jp/%7Eohmoto/Papers/t_y_polytope.pdf)" by Goda, Kamimura, and Ohmoto.

Note also the umbral inverse sequence to the Bernoulli polynomials, the Appell power polynomials

$$\hat{B}_n(x) = \frac{(x+1)^{n+1}-x^{n+1}}{n+1},$$

with the .e.g.f. $\frac{e^t-1}{t}\; e^{xt}$, is defined also by the umbral compositional inversion

$$B_n(\hat{B}.(x)) = x^n = \hat{B}_n(B.(x)),$$

so the

1. derivational property of the Appell Bernoulli polynomials

$$ \frac{(B_.(x)+1)^{n+1}}{n+1} - \frac{(B.(x))^{n+1}}{n+1} = \frac{(b.+x+1)^{n+1} - (b.+x)^{n+1}}{n+1}$$

$$ = \frac{B_{n+1}(x+1) - B_{n+1}(x)}{n+1}  = \hat{B}_n(B.(x)) = x^n = D \; \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1},$$

2. reciprocal relationship of the defining e.g.f.s of the moments of the inverse pair of Appell polynomial sequences

$$B(t) =e^{b.t}= \frac{t}{e^t-1},$$

$$\hat{B}(t) = e^{\hat{b}.t}=\frac{e^t-1}{t}, $$

3. reciprocity of the dual ops

$$T= B(D) = \frac{D}{e^D-1} = e^{b.D},$$

$$T^{-1}= \hat{B}(D) = \frac{e^D-1}{D} = e^{\hat{b}.D},$$

4. dual polynomial generating properties of the ops

$$T \; x^n = \frac{D}{e^D-1} \; x^n = e^{b.D} \; x^n = (b. + x)^n = B_n(x), $$

$$ T^{-1} \; x^n = \frac{e^D-1}{D} \; x^n = e^{\hat{b.}D} x^n = (\hat{b.}+x)^n = \hat{B}_n(x),$$

5. umbral compositional inverse relationship of the dual sets of polynomials

$$ B_n(\hat{B}.(x)) = T^{-1} \; T \; x^n = x^n = T \; T^{-1} \; x^n = \hat{B}_n(B.(x)),$$

6. and the discretizing property of the Todd operator

$$ x^n = T \; T^{-1} x^n = T \; \int_{x}^{x+1} t^n \; dt$$

$$ = T \frac{(x+1)^{n+1} - x^{n+1}}{n+1}$$

$$ =\frac{(B.(x)+1)^{n+1} -(B.(x))^{n+1}}{n+1} =  \hat{B}_n(B.(x))$$

are all intimately (and productively) interlinked, different facets of an Appell duality, and can be generalized via the Mellin transform. (The inverse $T^{-1}$ to the Todd operator $T$ is called the Bernoulli operator in "[Recent Contributions to the Calculus of Finite Differences: A Survey](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9502210)" by Loeb and Rota.)

This isn't the whole story--the relationships run even deeper through a Weyl algebra, Graves/Lie/Pincherle commutator, and ladder ops--but this perspective already leads to fruitful further exploration. For example, we obtain to boot in the limit as $n \to +\infty$ for the discretizing sum a modified Hurwitz zeta function as the generalization (interpolation) of the Bernoulli polynomials,

$$ B_{-s}(x) = s \; \zeta(s+1,x),$$

which inherits the properties of an Appell sequence of polynomials.

---

The 'shadow' equation is somewhat restrictive since it assumes the FT of $f(x)$ exists, which is not a necessary condition for the discretizing property to apply; e.g., note the similar Laplace transform [Abel-Plana formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Plana_formula).

With a different normalization for the FT,

$$FT(f(x)) =  \tilde{f}(\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  e^{-i 2\pi \omega x} f(x) \; dx,$$

and

$$f(b.+x) = e^{b.D_x} f(x) = \frac{D_x}{e^{D_x}-1} \; f(x) = \frac{D_x}{e^{D_x}-1} FT^{-1}[\tilde{f}(\omega)]$$

$$ = \frac{D_x}{e^{D_x}-1} \; \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  e^{i 2\pi \omega x} FT[f(x)] \; d\omega =  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  e^{i 2\pi \omega x} \frac{i 2\pi \omega}{e^{i 2\pi \omega}-1} FT[f(x)] \; d\omega. $$

Characterizing the action of the Todd operator using rather the [Mellin transform interpolation](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/353282/an-analytic-continuation-of-power-series-coefficients/379477#379477) a la Ramanujan/Hardy, gives an alternate, constructive route to the Hurwitz zeta function:

$$ B_{-s}(z) = (B.(z))^{-s} = (b.+z)^{-s} = e^{b.D_z} \; z^{-s}$$

$$ = e^{b.D_z} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-zt} \; \frac{t^{s-1}}{(s-1)!} \; dt$$

$$ =  \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-(b.+z)t} \; \frac{t^{s-1}}{(s-1)!} \; dt$$

$$ =\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-B.(z)t} \; \frac{t^{s-1}}{(s-1)!} \; dt $$

$$ = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{-t}{e^{-t}-1} \; e^{-zt} \frac{t^{s-1}}{(s-1)!} \; dt = s \; \zeta(s+1,z).$$

A series expansion for the Appell Bernoulli function for all real or complex $s$ and real or complex $z$ with $|z-1| <  1$ is given by the umbral binomial expansion

$$s \; \zeta(s+1,z) = B_{-s}(z)$$

$$ = (b.+z)^{-s} = (b. + 1 - 1 + z)^{-s} = (B.(1)+z-1)^{-s}$$

$$ =  \sum_{n \geq 0} \binom{-s}{n} B_{-s-n}(1) \; (z-1)^n =  \sum_{n \geq 0} \binom{-s}{n} (s+n) \; \zeta(s+n+1) \; (z-1)^n$$

where

$$(b.+1)^{-s} = (B.(1))^{-s} = B_{-s}(1) = s \; \zeta(s+1,1) = s \; \zeta(s+1)$$

with $\zeta(s)$, the Riemann zeta function.

Comment: Why did you point out the Appell anti-Bernoulli polynomials? This relationship is new to me, but I do not see how it is connected to the rest. Or did you simply show an example of the properties of Bernoulli polynomials? If Todd operator is connected to Umbrial calculus, it would be interesting.

Comment: Thanks to pointing out the name of this operator. I did not know it. It plays an important role in the theory I am currently working on (there are two variants of the theory, the first variant is described here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/115743/an-algebra-of-integrals/342651#342651 . In the theory variant1, $\text{reg }f(\omega_-+x)=T[f](x)$, very straightforward. In the theory variant2, $f(\omega_-+x)=T[f](x)|_{x\to\infty}$ and $f(x)|_{x\to\infty}=\int_{\omega_-}^{\omega_-+1}f(x)dx$.

Comment: We've crossed paths on this before--see the refs in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/266046/transformation-converting-power-series-to-bernoulli-polynomial-series/266058#266058 and in the latest version of "Computing the continuous discretely" by Beck and Robins the relation between the discretization and the Bernoulli polynomials is presented, but not quite in the form above.

Comment: Explicitly write out the umbral compositional inversion of  $\hat{B}_2(x)$ and mull over the sketch above, you should be able to see that the discretization, the umbral compositional inversion, the derivation property, and the sum/integral chain are all facets of the same mathematical machinery--calculus via the Bernoulli polynomials and their umbral inverse.  Of course a function can be written as a Taylor series in a disc of analyticity. Then acting on the divided powers gives a formal derivative. I've got a monograph on this I'll put on the web soon, detailing and extending earlier notes.

Comment: This is very interesting. I wonder if there could be formulation of umbrial calculus in terms of the linked theory of divergent series and integrals.

Comment: Yes, of course. I'll post over a hundred pages on this soon.

Comment: Since Bernoulli polynomials are connected to exponentiation of those divergent series, I wonder whether other classes of polynomials (Euler's etc) play some similar role there as well.

Comment: Please, give me a link to your work once it is available.

Comment: Will do. Related: "Finite-part integrals and the Euler-Maclaurin expansion" by Lyness https://www.osti.gov/servlets/purl/10121989

Comment: By the way, your $b.$ corresponds to my $\omega_-$. Literally, $b.^n=b_n=\text{reg }\omega_-^n$

Comment: The problem with your approach is in that you ignore the irregular part, counting all numbers with the same regular part as equal.

Comment: Another work in this direction but with the same problem (ignoring the infinite part, using only regular part): https://arxiv.org/abs/1011.3352 And also this may be useful: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1101.0770

Comment: Anixx, please don't set up straw men and engage in polemics--I'm really tired of such displays here and elsewhere.  $b_n=B_n(0) = (-1)^n B_n(1)$ are simply the classic Bernoulli numbers, which, of course, like any sequence of numbers, can be and have been generalized in dozens of ways to achieve different goals. The generalizations might or might not have problems, but the Bernoulli numbers are quite well-behaved and the relation between the Hurwitz zeta function and Bernoulli polynomials are well established in the literature.

Comment: I make no use of the, in general divergent, Euler-Maclaurin formula. I simply pointed to the ref since you commented you had an interest in divergent forms.

Comment: What I meant is that your symbol $b.$ exponentiated gives Bernoulli numbers. In this way it behaves as my extended number $\omega_-$, which when exponentiated gives regular part equal to the Bernoulli numbers. The difference is, I treat it just as a number while your symbol $b.$ is treated in formal way using "umbral" formalism. Look at the linked article https://arxiv.org/abs/1011.3352, they call it "Bernoulli operator".

Comment: I can treat it as a number because I consider it to be constituted of two parts, the regular part and infinite part.

Comment: You (and Yu) have a different approach to 'umbral' calculus. It would be better to call my spin on it the umbral Sheffer operational calculus, where the key to understanding the applications are differential operators acting on polynomials (confirm 4) or functions analytic about zero or in the right-half of the complex plane. The trick is to find convergent or useful asymptotic interpretations when acting on non-polynomial expressions--the umbral notation can guide the search and often provide elegant reps.

Comment: The Appell umbral Sheffer calc (USC), such as for T, reflects that of symm. function theory and so is important in invariant theory. Lie theory is lying just below the surface. For an intro to USC, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191752/whats-umbral-calculus-about/1085165#1085165 and  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116633/is-there-a-formula-similar-to-fxa-ea-fracddxfx-to-express-f-al. For relations of USC to partitions, rooted trees, lattice paths, polytopes, free probability, compositional  inversion, algebraic geometry, integral ops, pdes ..., see my blog and MO posts.